# imapsync - more messages on host 2 than shows in summary and host 1

Tags: unix, synchronization, imap

I have used imapsync version 1.607.
I have 560 messages in INBOX on host1 and empty (new) mailbox on host2.
After synchronization I get summary that 560 messages were synchronized.
But when I check on host2 I see about 600 messages, some duplicates. Is there any option to awoid this duplicated messages?

Answer (score 0):

Imapsync can make duplicates with several runs under certain circumstances, but only after a second run at least.
See http://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Duplicates.txt

But when imapsync makes duplicates then it duplicates all messages, not a few. So I wonder what happen in your case.